# .compute function using radio buttons

Tags: vb.net, radio-button

I am using code that calculates the average of exams where the module code is CSC3047 as shown below:

```
avgObject = gradeTable.Compute("avg(exam)", "module_ID = CSC3047")
```

However i would like to calculate the average exam result where the module ID equals the selected value from a radio button which has a list of the modules.

Something like this:

```
avgObject = gradeTable.Compute("avg(exam)", "module_ID = radioList.selectedValue")
```

I know this is wrong but i have no idea how to accomplish this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Dim condition As String = "module_ID=" + radioList.SelectedItem.Value.ToString()   
avgObject = gradeTable.Compute("avg(exam)", condition)
```

Hope this will help you